# How to register a new Model in Django-Oscar Dashboard?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I forked `catalogue` app and added a new model in the new app's models.py

```
class BundleProductClass(Product):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name="bundle_products")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Bundle Product'
```

In admin.py registered the new model
`admin.site.register(BundleProductClass)`

I can see the new model in `/admin` url but in `/dashboard` it is not registered. What do I have to do to register it in dashboard view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oscar dashboard is not linked to the Django admin.

If you want to manage a model through the Oscar dashboard, you have to create your own views and [add them to the dashboard navigation](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/how_to_configure_the_dashboard_navigation.html).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the forked app admin.py worked for me

```
#catalogue/admin.py
from oscar.apps.catalogue.admin import *  # noqa
from modapps.catalogue.models import Brand

class BrandAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [ 'id']


admin.site.register(Brand, BrandAdmin)
```